# Code triggered on load prevents page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am trying to loop through an array which is stored in localStorage, it should create a new div with the information of each object stored in the array when the page loads.
However my page won't load when I add this portion of code:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('shift') !== null){
 var shift_info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shift'),10);
       for(var i = 0; i < shift_info.length; i = i + 1){
            $('#shifts_to_complete').append('<div id="'+ i +'" class="current_shift" data-role="fieldcontain"></div>');
            var obj = shift_info.pop();
            $('#'+ i +'').html('Location: ' + obj.shift_location + '<br>Date: ' + obj.shift_date + '<br>Shift Starts: ' + obj.start_time + '<br>Shift Ends: ' + obj.end_time + '<br>Hours Worked: ' + obj.duration + '<br>Pay for Shift: &pound' + shift_pay + '<br><button class="shift_button ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-b" id="btn_'+ length +'">Completed?</button>');
       }
    }
```

It appears to just the last two lines of code which prevent the page loading. Any ideas why?

Cheers
James

Comment: use this  $('#'+ i) instead of  $('#'+ i +'') on your last line, and seems there would be any syntax error.Try finding it in firebug

Comment: Also, the very last variable being put in to set an ID on the button is just id="btn_' + length + '" where maybe it should set to i

Comment: Ahh yes of course, thanks. It comes up saying that the object has no method 'pop' which seems odd (the core jquery file is not being called twice or anything like that as far as I am aware)

Comment: @maxinacube you are correct, thanks nearly missed that

Answer (score 0):

I had stupidly missed out an `obj.` so there was an undefined variable.